# How to add text to another data column iif boolean is true?

Tags: sql

I would like to know if in the following if 'is_declined_race' is true then the ri.description could have 'Declined to answer' instead now it is blank and then I don't need to show the boolean field in the report.

```
select distinct
    c.full_name, c.dob, c.gender, c.ethnicity, 
    a.race_info_id, c.is_declined_race, c.id_no, 
    c.Current_age, ri.description,
    program_name, program_enrollment_name, actual_date, end_Date
from 
    all_people_expanded_view c 
    Left outer join (race a 
    inner join race_info ri on ri.race_info_id = a.race_info_id) on a.people_id = c.people_id
    left outer join program_enrollment_view e on c.people_id =e.people_id
where c.id_no <> 'N/A'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this with a `case` or an `iif()` depending on which system you're using.

Case example:

```
select distinct
    c.full_name, c.dob, c.gender, c.ethnicity, 
    a.race_info_id, c.is_declined_race, c.id_no, 
    c.Current_age, 
    case c.is_declined_race
        when 1
            then 'Declined to answer'
        when 0
            then ri.description
    end as [description],
    program_name, program_enrollment_name, actual_date, end_Date
from 
    all_people_expanded_view c 
    Left outer join (race a 
    inner join race_info ri on ri.race_info_id = a.race_info_id) on a.people_id = c.people_id
    left outer join program_enrollment_view e on c.people_id =e.people_id
where c.id_no <> 'N/A'
```

iif() example:

```
select distinct
    c.full_name, c.dob, c.gender, c.ethnicity, 
    a.race_info_id, c.is_declined_race, c.id_no, 
    c.Current_age, 
    iif(c.is_declined_race = 1, 'Declined to answer', ri.description) as [description],
    program_name, program_enrollment_name, actual_date, end_Date
from 
    all_people_expanded_view c 
    Left outer join (race a 
    inner join race_info ri on ri.race_info_id = a.race_info_id) on a.people_id = c.people_id
    left outer join program_enrollment_view e on c.people_id =e.people_id
where c.id_no <> 'N/A'
```

Comment: Thanks it is the IFF. We don't have access to the vendors database so I dont know the exact specs.

Comment: @Pinkab No worries, don't forget to mark it as answered if it's worked

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE

```sql
CASE
    WHEN is_declined_race THEN 'Declined to answer'
    ELSE ri.description
END AS racedescription
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write case statement in sql query, I am supposing you are using MS-SQL

You can use below sql query in that I have added case statement on `is_declined_race` and if its value is 1 which I am considering a bit field then it will return 'Declined to answer' and in else it will return whatever store in `ri.description` field.

```
select distinct
    c.full_name, c.dob, c.gender, c.ethnicity, 
    a.race_info_id, (CASE WHEN c.is_declined_race = 1 THEN 'Declined to answer' ELSE ri.description END) AS description, c.id_no, 
    c.Current_age,
    program_name, program_enrollment_name, actual_date, end_Date
from 
    all_people_expanded_view c 
    Left outer join (race a 
    inner join race_info ri on ri.race_info_id = a.race_info_id) on a.people_id = c.people_id
    left outer join program_enrollment_view e on c.people_id =e.people_id
where c.id_no <> 'N/A'
```

Hope this help.